# Zbar doesnt find code

Tags: c++, zbar

i'm trying to find a QR-code using the ZBar library(zbar.sourceforge.net) and opencv.

Here is my code:

```
string findIDIncircle(Mat img, double* angle)
{
    ImageScanner scanner; 
    zbar_image_scanner_set_config(scanner, ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);
    int width = img.cols;  
    int height = img.rows;  
    uchar *raw = (uchar *)img.data;
    Image image(width, height, "Y800", raw, width * height);
    scanner.scan(image);
    SymbolSet symbols = image.get_symbols();
    for(Image::SymbolIterator symbol = image.symbol_begin(); symbol != image.symbol_end(); symbol++)
    {
        string data = symbol->get_data();
        vector<Point> vp;
        int n = symbol->get_location_size();  
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {  
         vp.push_back(Point(symbol->get_location_x(i),symbol->get_location_y(i))); 
      }  
      RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(vp);
        *angle = r.angle;
        return data;
    }
    return "";
}
```

But the code doesn't find anything. i checked the argument using imwrite on img and the image is correct and very clear(it was generated with http://www.qrcode-generator.de/)
can anyone tell me, where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solved it myself, had to convert it to grayscale:

```
Mat gray;
cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
uchar *raw = (uchar *)gray.data;
```